# Definition of the Tangent Space

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm watching [a series of lectures](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLBY4G2o7DhF38OEvEImfR2heX7Szmq5Gs) on differential geometry, and I've run into a bit of a problem with the definition of the tangent space. We first defined a tangent space as $\{(p,v) | v \in \mathbb{R}^n\}$, which makes sense to me: it's the set of all vectors attached at point $p$. We then defined the directional derivative as

$$
(Df)(p,v) = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(p + tv) - f(p)}{t}
$$

We expanded that to this:

$$
(Df)(p,v) = \left( \sum_{i = 0}^{n}v_i \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\right|_{p}
\right) f$$

This makes sense to me; we have defined the directional derivative as an operator that is applied to the function.

Here's the part where I lose the plot. I'm then told that, if I think about it, the portion inside the parentheses is really interchangeable with $(p,v)$. I'm afraid that I've thought about it, and I can't see the equivalence. $\sum_{i = 0}^{n}v_i \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\right|_{p}$ is an operator (isn't it?) whereas $(p,v)$ is a ordered pair of elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Does that mean that the expression $(p,v)(f)$ makes sense? What would that mean?

I must be thinking about this the wrong way; can someone clarify?

Comment: Think about the information contained in the expression inside the parentheses. It is exactly the information conveyed by the ordered pair $\left(p,v\right)$. Then, we can define the notation $\left(p,v\right)\left(f\right)$ to "mean" $\left(Df\right)\left(p,v\right)$. It's a matter of formal notation, as far as I can make out.

Comment: It is essentially a reconceptualization of tangent vectors, shifting from viewing them as directions on the manifold to viewing them as the directional derivative operators themselves. (Acting on scalar fields on the manifold.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the phrase "the portion inside the parentheses is really interchangeable with $(p,v)$" is quite misleading. This is not really true -- as you correctly observed, $(p,v)$ is an ordered pair of elements of $\mathbb R^n$, while the expression in parentheses is an operator on functions.

What is true is that there is a linear map from the set $\{(p,v)|v\in\mathbb R^n\}$ (let's call that the ***geometric tangent space***) into the set of linear differential operators on functions, which takes the pair $(p,v)$ to the "directional derivative operator" that you wrote down. The image of this map is the set of ***derivations at $\boldsymbol p$***, which is the set of all linear maps $X\colon C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)\to \mathbb R$ that satisfy this product rule:
$$
X(fg) = f(p)X(g) + g(p)X(f).
$$
The geometric tangent space is thus *canonically isomorphic* to the set of derivations at $p$.

Why does this matter? Because on an abstract manifold, the geometric tangent space doesn't have any coordinate-independent meaning, but the space of derivations at $p$ does. So we take the space of derivations at $p$ as our *definition* of the tangent space to $M$ at $p$.

Once you get comfortable with the canonical isomorphism between the geometric tangent space and the space of derivations at $p$, then you might start thinking of them as "interchangeable." But when you're first trying to learn this stuff, it's more productive to think of them as canonically isomorphic.

Comment: Hi Prof. Lee, I am reading your textbook Introduction to Smooth Manifolds and have a question about the definition of tangent spaces. You defined the geometric tangent space to $\mathbb{R}^n$ at $p$ to be the set $\{(p,v)|v\in\mathbb R^n\}$ in the text. So I guess the geometric tangent space to $\mathbb{S}^2$ at $p$ would be defined as $\{(p,v)|v\in\mathbb S^2\}$, which is a unit sphere centered at $p$. But shouldn't a tangent space to a ball at some point be a plane? I have been stuck here for a while. Thanks for your answer in advance.

Comment: @SamWong: I didn't define the geometric tangent space for a submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$; only for $\mathbb R^n$ itself. As you observed, mimicking the same definition would not make any sense for a submanifold. Tangent spaces to submanifolds are treated in Chapter 5 of my book.

Comment: Oh ok, I will read the chapter 5 later. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Professor Lee. I am a bit confused on the definition of the tangent space as derivations. One important property of that definition is to write a tangent vector $v \in T_p M$ as $v = \sum_{\mu =1}^{m} v(x^{\mu}) \cdot \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}} \right|_p \ \ $, where $x=(x^1,...,x^m)$ is a local chart around $p$. But generaly $dom(x) \neq M$ and $v$ is supposed to act just in functions of $C^{\infty} M$. Can you clarify for me, please?

Comment: @Gustavo: Because the value $v(f)$ depends only on the values of $f$ in an arbitrarily small neighborhood of $p$, a vector $v\in T_pM$ can act on functions that are defined only in a neighborhood of $p$. This is discussed on page 56 of my _Introduction to Smooth Manifolds_ (2nd ed.).

Answer (score 4):

The usual notation for the tangent space at a point $p$ of a differentiable manifold $M$ is $T_pM$. By the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space) you can see that this space is  a vector space that has the same dimension $n$ as the manifold $M$. The elements of $T_pM$ are not ''all vectors attached at point $p$'' as you say, but the vectors, attached at $p$, that stay in the tangent plane to the manifold at $p$.

So, in a notation as $ T_pM=\{(p,v):v\in \mathbb{R}^n\}$ $p$ really is simply a parameter, that specifies the point where we take the tangent plane.

The vectors in $T_pM$ can be represented, as you notice, as
$$
\sum_{i = 0}^{n}v_i \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\right|_{p}
$$
and we can can think at $T_pM$ as a vector space of linear operators with basis
$$
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}|_{p}\right)  \qquad i=1,2\cdots n
 \quad p \in M
$$
We have one such space for every $p$ and we can consider the set of all such tangent spaces:
$$
TM=\bigcup_{p\in M}\{(p,v):v\in T_pM \}
$$ 
In this notation the presence of $p$ has clearly  the sense of parametrize all the tangent spaces, but note that  the element of $T_pM$ is $v$, not the couple $(p,v)$, and $TM$ is the [tangent bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_bundle) of $M$.